# How to set the background color of the content that should be displayed in a fancybox in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have a div that forms the content of the fancybox. I need to change the background color of the div which froms the content of the fancybox on click of a link which will popup the fancybox? How to change it in jquery?

```
/* Href */
    <a href="#" id="link">click here</a>

/* FancyBox */

    $('#link').on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();


                $.fancybox({

                    'autoScale'         : false,
                    'autoSize'      : false,
                    'autoDimensions': false,
                    'titleShow'         : false,
                    'padding' : 0,
                    'overlayOpacity': '.8',
                    'overlayColor': '#333',
                    'transitionIn': 'none',
                    'transitionOut': 'none',
                    'centerOnScroll': true,
                    'showCloseButton': true,
                    'closeBtn'          : true,
                    'scrolling'         : true,
                    'height': 'auto',
                    'width': 120,
                    'minHeight'         : 160,
                    'minWidth'          : 10,
                    'maxWidth'          : 780,
                    'type':'ajax',
                    'href' : 'url/something.html',

                    helpers : {

                        overlay : {closeClick: false}
                    },
                    'beforeShow'  : function(){
                        var closer = $('button.buttonCTW');
                        closer.on('click', function() {
                            $.fancybox.close();
                        });
                        $.fancybox.update();
                    },

                });
            });
```

Comment: Post your relevant code.

Comment: How about altering the css in `beforeShow`?

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't posted any code.. this is just a shot in the dark but this should do the trick:

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/remix1201/gw0vnzcv/

```
$(".linkClass").click(function(){
    $(".targetClass").css("background-color","YOURCOLORCODEHERE");
});
```

Comment: sorry i didnt post any code earlier. I've tried this option already. since, the content of the fancybox will not present in dom at the time of click event, we can't change the css of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the background colour of fancy box before it is shown.

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
      beforeShow: function() { 
          $('fancybox-skin').css('background-color', 'red');       
      }
 });
```